# Sending mail from within VB app; better way then SMTP?

Tags: vb.net, email

I have developed a little program in VB. I want to add a form so that people can contact me from within the application (and it will also send some debug data along).
Of course, I can use System.Net.Mail to send an email. But I was wondering if this is the right way to use this method in a 'public' application.
Using System.Net.Mail, I must use a SMTP server. I have my own private SMTP server, so that is not a problem, but some ISP's may block SMTP servers other than their own. So this would end up the end user with an error. 
So, are there (better) ways to send an e-mail from within an application, preferably without using an SMTP server?

Thanks!

Comment: I Also took a look to see if I could generate a mail message using Google API. But it looks like there is no client for accomplishing this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a pay email service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). They have an SMTP relay and Web API, which is the solution I believe you are looking for.

Read the [Developer Documentation](http://sendgrid.com/docs/) for more information.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for the input. SendGrid looks promising I'll take a look at this!

Comment: @mitch2k - if you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept and/or up-vote the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have an SMTP server, you should use it. Pretty unlikely any IT department is going to block **OUTGOING** traffic on port 25. If you want, you can either catch the error (on rare occation-never) and use a MAILTO: instead, so they can still submit an email.

The other option, if you really want something different, is to create you own web service (I assume you have a web server if you have your own SMTP) that you can send emails through.  Then you can communicate through port 80, which should not be blocked either.

Just remember, with System.Net.Mail and the Web Service idea, an internet connection is required. With MAILTO:, most email applications will hold the email until it is back online.